# Using a cursor to create a counter in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm having trouble creating a repeating counter variable in SQL. Here is what I am looking to do-

```
x_id       date                 num       p_id       Counter
2113       4/1/2013              11           444         1
2113       4/1/2013              11           445         2
2113       4/1/2013              21           448         3
2113       4/1/2013              21           460         4
2113       4/1/2013              21           461         5
2113       4/1/2013              31           463         6
2116       4/1/2013              7              982         1
2116       4/1/2013              7              985         2
2116       4/1/2013              8              987         3
```

When I order this data by x_id, date, num, and  p_id, I have everything the way I want it to create a counter column.

What I'm having difficulty with is breaking and restarting this counter column where I want to. I want the counter to start over each time a new x_id/ date pairing occurs (so if either changes, the counter should go back to 1).

I have been told that creating a cursor is the best way to go about doing this, but I can't find an example online of anything that looks similar enough.

It seems like it should be a relatively simple thing to do..can anyone help me out?

Thanks so much!

Comment: So in the scenario above first 6 rows should have counter = 1 and the last 3 should have counter = 2?

Comment: What database system and what version of said database system?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I am using MAMP and Sequel Pro on a Mac if that helps. What Id like (once the data is ordered as it is above) is for the counter to increase by one for x_id/date pairings, and then start over when a new pairing occurs- so the the counter should look as it does above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for MySQL:

You don't need a cursor for this

```
SELECT
yt.*,
@counter := CASE WHEN @prev_x != x_id OR @prev_date != `date` THEN 1 ELSE @counter + 1 END AS counter,
@prev_x := x_id,
@prev_date := `date`
FROM yourTable yt
, (SELECT @counter:=1, @prev_x:=NULL, @prev_date:=NULL) vars
ORDER BY x_id, `date`, num, p_id
```

Comment: Although `date` doesn't change in the sample data, the narrative seems to say that `date` changes should also reset the counter.

Comment: That's correct. I should have made it more clear, but the date does change and would reset the counter.

Comment: Fixed it to consider date column changes.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a database system that supports the window functions, then this is `ROW_NUMBER`s job:

```
select x_id,date,num,p_id,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x_id, date ORDER BY num, p_id) as counter
from table
```

[SQL Server help for `ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), but it's also support by many other database systems, such as Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2 (but not MySQL):

> Returns the sequential number of a row within a partition of a result set, starting at 1 for the first row in each partition

Comment: +1 (for being right).  And, `row_number()` is ANSI standard and supported by most major databases.  At least:  SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, Teradata, and Postgres and its many derivatives.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - added a partial list to my answer and highlighted the one I was thinking of that I know doesn't support it (as always, it would be much easier if the OP had included database system information)

Comment: This would be perfect, but I am using MySQL. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @SoxBoston - looks like fancyPants has provided [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17836404/15498), but I can't comment to it's correctness (it looks at the moment to only switch on `x_id` values, probably because `date` doesn't change in your sample data, but can probably be modified)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using SQL Server/TSQL:

Don't use cursor, use [DENSE_RANK()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) function instead.

```
SELECT x_id, date, num, p_id, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY x_id, date) as Counter FROM Table
```

*UPDATE*: Re-read the question again, this may not be the right solution for the above scenario, it will keep counter the same until the related values change (1 for the 1st six rows, 2 for the second three, etc.)

Comment: `DENSE_RANK` is the wrong function when a counter is wanted. It may assign the same value to multiple rows.

Comment: I beleive that was the OP's original idea (asked in the comments, but didn't receive response yet)

Comment: "a new x_id/ date pairing occurs ... the counter should go back to 1"

Comment: Should've been more attentive, thanks. Will comment my solution